# wordpress šųūįė letters in wpdb query

Tags: php, wordpress

I get posts by first letter this way:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
                "
                SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE post_title LIKE '$request%'
                AND post_type = 'post'
                AND post_status = 'publish'
                ORDER BY post_title ASC;
                "
            );
```

And I have a problem. If I want to get posts that starts from Ą letter, wordpress gives me posts that starts from A, if Š gives S etc.
How can I get posts with strict letter start?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using a "Accent Insensitive" [database collation](https://database.guide/what-is-collation-in-databases/). Depending on your exact server set up, you're probably using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `latin1_swedish_ci`. You'll most likely need to change that to `utf8_YOURREGION_ci` or just `utf8mb4_bin`.

The easiest way to change the DB Collation is directly in phpMyAdmin if you have access to it.

Comment: Is it only one way? I like, that search find results without writing exact letters, but only in one query I want to use exact letters.